# Who first translated the Bible in French?

Tags: translation-philosophy

Good day,

I found this ambiguous Wikipedia page that manages to say in a few lines that Pierre Robert Olivétan is the first one to have translated the Bible in French and then says that he translated the first **protestant** Bible in 1535, based on his teacher's work, Jacques Lefèvre d'Étaples.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Robert_Oliv%C3%A9tan

Now, it does say that Lefèvre's entry that he completed a full translation of the Bible in 1534 based on the Hebrew and Greek texts: "The publication and its revised edition based on the Hebrew and the Greek texts were printed by Merten de Keyser in Antwerp in 1534."

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Lef%C3%A8vre_d'%C3%89taples#Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Lef%C3%A8vre_d%27%C3%89taples#Life)

So which is it? And why is the Olivétan translation said to be the first, when it clearly seems to be the second? Do you think the title of the first French Bible was attributed to Olivétan to legitimize the reformation, knowing that Lefèvre remained a Catholic his whole life?

Thank you!

Comment: The earlier translation was not from the original languages but from Latin.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_into_French

Comment: Alright, so the sentence on the screen-shot (from Lefèvre's Wikipedia biography) would mean that "he corrected his original vulgate transltation in the light of the original Hebrew and Greek textes"? https://i.imgur.com/2jVCrDX.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Watchtower Online Library](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/101997884) says:

> With the invention of the printing press and movable type by Johannes
> Gutenberg about 1450, France was swept along by the printing
> revolution in Europe. Three French cities—Paris, Lyons, and
> Rouen—became important centers of printing, bulwarks in the defense of
> the Bible.a
>
> Until this stage of the struggle, French Bible translations had been
> based on the Latin Vulgate. The Latin text had become tainted with
> numerous errors after a thousand years of repeated copying, but the
> church clung to the Vulgate. However, **French Catholic Jacques Lefèvre
> d’Étaples decided to make the Bible accessible to the people. In 1530
> he translated the Vulgate into French, correcting some of its errors
> by referring to Hebrew and Greek manuscripts that had recently become
> available. He also removed the confusing doctrinal explanations that
> the church had inserted into the text.**
>
> Lefèvre’s translation quickly came under attack. Some versions had to
> be printed outside France. These were put on the list of books banned
> by the church. For a time Lefèvre had to seek refuge in Strasbourg,
> then a free imperial city to the east of France. Nevertheless, his
> translation was a success.
>
> **The first French translation of the Bible based on the original
> language texts was published in 1535. The translator was French
> Protestant Pierre-Robert Olivétan**, a cousin of Reformer John Calvin.
> Because of the opposition of the church, it could not be printed in
> France, so this translation was printed in Neuchâtel, Switzerland, a
> fledgling Protestant community. Olivétan’s French Bible translation
> served as the standard for many subsequent revisions and Bible
> translations into other languages.

[SMU Libraries](https://bridwell.omeka.net/exhibits/show/prothrobible/reformation/frenchvulgate) says:

> **The first French version of the Vulgate Bible, translated by Jacques Lefèvre d’Etaples (c. 1455–1536), was published in 1530.** Prior to
> Lefèvre’s translation, the only French “Bibles” were abridgements of
> the Biblia historiale, a medieval paraphrase of the historical books
> of the Bible. **In this second edition of 1534, Lefèvre included
> introductory material that revealed Protestant influences, which drew
> censure from the Catholic Church.** The displayed opening includes a
> woodcut of the six days of Creation at the beginning of Genesis.

[britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/biblical-literature/Medieval-and-modern-versions-Dutch-French-and-German) says:

> The deep conflicts that characterized the history of Christianity in
> France made it **difficult for one authoritative version to emerge.** The
> **first complete French Bible was produced in the 13th century at the
> University of Paris**, and toward the end of that century Guyart des
> Moulins executed his Bible historiale. Both works served as the basis
> of future redactions, of which the Bible printed in Paris (date given
> variously as 1487, 1496, or 1498) by order of King Charles VIII is a
> good example.
>
> **The real history of the French Bible began in Paris in 1523 with the
> publication of the New Testament, almost certainly the work of the
> reformer Jacques Lefèvre d’Étaples (Faber Stapulensis).** The Old
> Testament appeared in Antwerp in 1528 and **the two together in 1530 as
> the Antwerp Bible.** **The first true Protestant version came out in
> Serrières, near Neuchâtel, five years later, the work of Pierre
> Robert, called Olivétan.** This version was frequently revised
> throughout the 16th century, the most-celebrated editions being
> Calvin’s of 1546 and that of Robert Estienne (Stephanus) of 1553.
> Roman Catholics produced a new version, the Louvain Bible of 1550,
> based on both Lefèvre and Olivétan. Modernizations of Olivétan
> appeared in succeeding centuries. The most important French version of
> the 20th century is the Jerusalem Bible, prepared by professors at the
> Dominican École Biblique de Jérusalem (Paris 1949–54, complete 1956).

**In summary:**

**Jacques Lefèvre d’Étaples:** Lefèvre's full translation of the Vulgate into French was **published in 1530**. This translation was significant because it corrected errors **in the Latin Vulgate** and made the Bible more accessible to the people. Lefèvre's work also included introductory material that revealed Protestant influences, drawing criticism from the Catholic Church.

**Pierre Robert Olivétan:** Olivétan's translation, **published in 1535**, **was the first French version of the Bible based on the original Hebrew and Greek texts.** It was a Protestant version, produced amidst conflicts between Catholicism and Protestantism in France. Olivétan's translation served as a standard for subsequent revisions and translations into other languages.

**To conclude:** While Lefèvre's translation preceded Olivétan's, Olivétan's work was significant as the first Protestant version based on the original language texts. Therefore, both Lefèvre and Olivétan made important contributions to the history of the French Bible translation.

Comment: Thank you so much Jason_ for taking the time to answer this question. It comes at an important time in my life. May God bless you and your family. If it's not already the case, please checkout this gospel presentation: https://codeforfaith.com